# where to find the @max.intValue

Tags: iphone, ios

i use the follow code to get the max value:

```
 NSArray *allValues = @[ [NSNumber numberWithInt:20],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:36],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:84],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:11],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:28]];

int max = [[allValues valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];
int min = [[allValues valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"] intValue];
```

but i have a question,what document can tell me  that where is the KeyPath link @max.intValue
or @min.intValue.if i know the key path i can know do other effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find this information in the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE):

> @max
>
> The @max operator compares the values of the property specified
>   by the key path to the right of the operator and returns the maximum
>   value found. The maximum value is determined using the compare: method
>   of the objects at the specified key path. The compared property
>   objects must support comparison with each other. If the value of the
>   right side of the key path is nil, it is ignored.
>
> @min
>
> The @min operator compares the values of the property specified
>   by the key path to the right of the operator and returns the minimum
>   value found. The minimum value is determined using the compare: method
>   of the objects at the specified key path. The compared property
>   objects must support comparison with each other. If the value of the
>   right side of the key path is nil, it is ignored.

Comment: +1 for faster than me :) Now I don't need to post same link :)